# Index Organized Table Fragmentation

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, fragmentation

Hi I have been looking into Index Organized Tables. I am little confused about the fragmentation aspects. Oracle states that

"heavy volume causes fragmentation resulting in a frequent need to reorganize. Because an     index-organized table can be reorganized online and without invalidating its secondary indexes, the window of unavailability is greatly reduced or eliminated."

Does this mean the table can still be accessed when it is being reorganized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I have researched this a little more and yes the ONLINE means that the existing IOT can be accessed whilst a new one is being rebuilt.

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dj15MpOf4FIC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=index+organized+table+fragmentation&source=bl&ots=UBXd4W4Q8g&sig=qNzY_PvrBx0j_5cQ_mx-zNOV584&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HgQ8U6-YHNSM0wWd94GABg&ved=0CGwQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=index%20organized%20table%20fragmentation&f=false